# Why are there are so many words for "zero"?

Tags: etymology, synonyms, numbers, mathematics

*Null*, *nil* and *naught* are all synonyms of *zero*, and to my knowledge, *zero* is the only number that has this many cognitive synonyms, if not more. Why is this?

Does it have to do with English being significantly influenced by both Germanic and Latin, leading to many synonyms with different historic roots, this number being an example of that? Or are there other factors at play? Zero is more than just a number, it is a concept, the concept of *nothing*, which would probably warrant many entities putting a name on it; does it have anything to do with that?

Comment: You can't think of a single solitary one lone number that has that many synonyms?

Comment: @Laurel I can think or a couple. The pair I have in mind is a real dynamic duo. It took me a while but I hunted them down and strung them up like a brace of pheasants. Or I should say they really dragged me to the truth like a yoke of oxen; nay, speedier, a span of coursers!

Comment: I can't think of any. There are synonyms for "one", but not the noun "one", only the adjective.

Comment: @DanBron If I guessed what you were hinting at correctly, then I have to disagree. Duo is not a synonym of two, as duo is two people doing whatever, and two is abstract concept of the number two.

Comment: Oh wait, I just thought of another one. So now we have a trio! A triad of terms! I feel like such a winner, like I just turned a trey on the flop. How could I have been happy with a dingy duo, with such a triumphant triumvirate for the taking! A silly span of coursers? Nay, a troika of thoroughbreds trampling the thoroughfare!

Comment: OP, are you restricting your question to only synonyms for the mathematical entity "zero" used as a noun? If so, please indicate that in your question. Otherwise, as others have done, we can easily show a lot of synonyms for the number 1 to 3 as well, making your assumption that 0 is special incorrect.

Comment: @A.Kvåle The comments are silly but the message is not. You’ve actually asked a deep question here that occurs to me with some frequency. English (and other languages) have all these fossils of an earlier time, which share a deep genomic relationship though their phenotypes are sometimes totally unalike. I think it reflects a key insight that humanity has to discover: [cont’d].

Comment: [cont’d] exactly your “abstractness of numbers”. That a pair of shoes, a brace of birds, a hole of oxen... all have something in common. Something abstract. A “twoness”. I think this must have come as a *eureka* moment in the history of man, and highlights the singularity human capability that keeps us apart from other animals. I think this moment of eureka is supported by the fact that all the numbers with many names are small integers: we didn’t see a commonality for a long time, but when we did it allowed us to see *the integers as a concept*, opening entirely new vistas for the species.

Comment: When did zero enter the English language? Shouldn’t it be regarded as an academic term (synonym) for none? And isn’t it rather obvious that none is a concept as well as a numeral? But that’s just my opinion, like most answers to why questions (I’ve edited out “how come”). So let’s just close.

Comment: What I meant is that, duo, or a pair is distinct from two because they have more implications than two. Two is simply the concept of two existences, whilst a duo is two people or two elements working together for a specific effect. A pair implies that it is two of the same thing, as in, a pair of socks. Though I will agree that "two" and "duo" are synonymous, they are not synonyms, as synonymy is a spectrum, from everything to direct, indisputable synonyms that mean exactly the same thing, to things that have the same connotations and/or have similar meaning. @DanBron

Comment: A comment on your editing @David. I know "why" and "how come" basically mean the same thing, I believe "how come" have other connotations with it that better suit the kind of answer I'm looking for. With "why" one can expect a brief answer saying the exact reason, whilst with "how come" one can expect more of an elaborated answer perhaps touching on more of the aspects of the explanation. Though that's just my understanding, and you probably know better than me since English is my second language.

Comment: @DanBron 'Span of coursers'? What _is_ that? What does that have to do with 'two'?

Comment: @Mitch A dictionary would clear it all up.

Comment: I don't know, but I bet other languages are also fairly expressive for zero and one.

Comment: @DanBron hm... never heard of that. It sounds a bit like a term of venery.

Comment: @DanBron I made a one-word edit to my post that I makes it a lot clearer what I'm saying with a certain point I make in my question. I changed "...zero is the only number that has this many synonyms..." by adding the word "cognitive". Cognitive synonyms are synonyms with exactly the same meaning. I didn't previously know about this term before user "mama" told me in a comment here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/484973/are-two-and-duo-synonyms

Comment: @Laurel - Nada.

Comment: I don't know the answer for this, but one guess that I would make is that it might be related to the concept of zero tardy appearance with respect to other numbers. Zero was not even considered a number until quite late, specially in Europe. Probably many of the other words evolved from words for nothing, nothingness etc. Then much later the Arabs taught Europe about zero and the meanings converged.

Answer (score 3):

It's not that there are so many words for the digit or number zero, but that [there are so many words for 'nothing'](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/nothing) which are then associated with the mathematical number.

---

'Why' is a question we all want to know the answer to, but is often difficult with words. The usual way to deal with it is by turning the question away from causes into description; 'here is the data, it just is'.

Zero, and other numbers, are usually strange grammatically. They're usually adjectives ('five sheep'), and yet also sort of nouns ('Sheep? I have five.' (notice that 'red' or 'hungry' don't fit there). The small numbers all have multiple versions too: one - single, ace, singleton, nonce, loner, two - pair, deuce, double. [Zero might be considered special](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0) because it really wasn't a 'thing', as a mathematical number, until, let's just pick one to set it, [458 AD in India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0#History). But that's a bit of misdirection because 'nothingness', or 'nothing' or 'nought', and separately, 'zero' and 'cypher' have much longer etymological histories than just for a little symbol used in arithmetic.

Given only the recent introduction of that little symbol may be motivation for wondering why it has such a rich vocabulary. But I think that is where the answer lies, in that there is ample historical use of the concept of nothingness, without any kind of specific mathematical notation, that one could expect lots of vocabulary items for 'nothing'.

After all, there are a lot of words for *not* nothing: much, many, several, a lot, a few, boatloads, numerous, myriad, etc, etc, etc. without having to posit some arcane numerical system (arcane because it was the province, in any society, of the very small set of bean counters; before modern education, literacy was rare, and numeracy even moreso).

The explanation of why there are so many words for 'zero' is really that [there are so many words for 'nothing'.](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/nothing)

Comment: I don't think **any** grammarian would classify numerals as adjectives nowadays. The big question is whether to include them in the quantifier class or not (when they need a class of their own).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ontologically speaking, numerals are much closer to adjectives (as a large inclusive group) than to the other of the classic Latinate parts of speech. Would you be more comfortable if I said 'like adjectives' rather than just 'adjectives'?

Comment: 'Classically (though not nowadays) designated 'adjectives'? And surely ELU has moved on from the traditional 8 POS's? Though I'm still fighting for 'directional particle' and 'locational particle' in some cases where others lump into '[intransitive] preposition'.